# Convert json in a request to array in golang

Tags: go

How can I convert a json array to an array of structs? Example:

```
[
  {"name": "Rob"},
  {"name": "John"}
]
```

I'm retrieving the json from a request:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

How would I unmarshal this into an array?

Comment: If your structures start getting complicated or long, this tool may save a few minutes of typing: http://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: @Matt: Oh wow! Can't thank you enough for that tool, it's an absolute must for a Go n00b like me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you simply use `json.Unmarshal` for this. Example:

```
import "encoding/json"


// This is the type we define for deserialization.
// You can use map[string]string as well
type User struct {

    // The `json` struct tag maps between the json name
    // and actual name of the field
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

// This functions accepts a byte array containing a JSON
func parseUsers(jsonBuffer []byte) ([]User, error) {

    // We create an empty array
    users := []User{}

    // Unmarshal the json into it. this will use the struct tag
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBuffer, &users)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // the array is now filled with users
    return users, nil

}
```